# TiWebView: Submitting data to a self signed https URL from a local html file on iOS cause error

Tags: ios, ssl, appcelerator

Due to compliance constraint, our app need to HTTP post data to a separate system that is hosted in a self signed HTTPS environment. The app is build in Appcelerator / Titanium framework (SDK 6.0.4).

We have created a local html file and the app will populate the relevant fields, and through evaljs post the data to the server. On Android we are able to complete the flow. However on iOS we will get the following error:

```
The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xx.xx.xx.xx” which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

Method tried:

1. Setting `ignoreSslError` to `false`
2. Adding `ATS allow arbitrary and exception domain settings`
3. Install the self signed cert Root, SubCA and RootCA cer file into the device.

All doesn't solve the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check this property : 
validatesSecureCertificate : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-validatesSecureCertificate